# Slow request in CakePHP 2.3

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, cakephp

## Setup

- CakePHP 2.3.5
- PHP 5.3.8
- Apache 2.2
- PostgreSQL 8.4
- Windows 7 Professional x64

---

This, is one of a lot situations in my project, **with a CakePHP need more than 1 second to render a simple view**. I test all the possible requests... ajax, json, get, post, put, delete... in each one, CakePHP is slow.

*Obs.: I'm working localhost: database, server, git, etc. All in my machine.*

---

### Problem 1)

I have this code:

```
$('#multiple').delegate('.plus-payment', 'click', 
  function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'authorizations', 'action' => 'credit_card', $table_num, $check_num)); ?>",
      data: {},
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
        
        $('#multiple').append(data);
        return false;

      }
    });
      }
);
```

The action:

```
public function credit_card($table_num, $check_num)
{
  
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {

  $this->layout = 'ajax';
  $this->render('modal_credit_card');

} elseif ($this->request->is('post')) {
```

This, call this view:

```
<div class="payment">
    <div class="swipe">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('Authorization.swipe.', array('value' => 'by_hand', 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'hiddenField' => false, 'class' => 'swipeoff')) ?><?php echo __('Manual') ?>
        </label>
    </div>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Authorization.card_number.', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'placeholder' => __('Swipe Card'))) ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Authorization.exp_date.', array('required' => false, 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'expdate input-mini', 'placeholder' => __('Validade'))) ?>

    <span class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">$</span>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Authorization.amount.', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'input-small', 'placeholder' => __('Valor'))) ?>
    </span>


    <a href='#' class="btn btn-success plus-payment"><i class="icon icon-plus icon-white"></i></a>
    <a href='#' class="btn btn-danger remove-payment"><i class="icon icon-trash icon-white"></i></a>
    <hr>
</div>
```

CakePHP need 2~3 seconds, to return the view.

So... why?

Is just a view, no database connection, no query, no conditions... just render.

**Obs.: Tested in PHP 5.4.8, and the request is executed in 0.2~1 second.** *I don't know why*

Comment: Have you tried using xdebug?

Comment: @xgalvin for check what? What the action doing? Or, what the cakephp is doing?

Comment: To see if there's a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Change debug to 0 in your `app/Config/bootstrap.php`  (around line 36):

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

When it's `2` (default for development purposes), it runs a LOT of extra processes including querying all your tables to check for updated schemas...etc etc.

If that's not it, you can use [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) to view not only details about everything that's being run, but also the time it takes for each individual process/query...etc etc and find where the issue is and/or what is taking the longest to run.

Comment: I test with debug 0, and without DebugKit. Same time.

Comment: The main point of my answer is, if you're not sure why it's running slow, look at the 'Timer' tab in DebugKit - THAT'S the answer... it shows you everything about how long every process takes, what is run...etc..etc.  At that point, you can come back and ask a question "Why does XYZ take so long to run" or, "Why is it running XYZ even though I didn't ask it to"...etc.  It will allow you to ask a more specific question.  For now, I think "use debugKit 'timer'" is the answer.

Comment: Controller action: 3 seconds. But controller action is 'everything'. I debug with xdebug in Sublime Text, and it's ok. Nothing strange unless the Model actions/querys.

Comment: How about under 'Sqllog' tab?  How many queries, and how long per query..etc?

Comment: No queries are executed. And, if I put `exit;` before render(), and the request is done in 0.2~1 second. But, if I remove the `exit;`and render is executed, the request need more than 2 seconds.